# Impossible to view the full chart with ggplot2 (size problem)

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, data-visualization

I have to draw charts with relatively long x ticks names. My problem is that the output look like this, so that it's impossible for me to see the entire chart but also to save it. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

My code is the following

```
ministerios_genders <- ggplot(dfm_m,aes(x = nombre_entidad,y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge") + scale_fill_manual("Gender", values = c("HOMBRE" = "blue", "MUJER" = "orange")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                     size=5, angle=75),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                     size=8, angle=90))

print(ministerios_genders + ggtitle("Gender visitors gap for \nthe most important entities") + ggeasy::easy_center_title() + labs(y = "Proportions", x = "nombre del entidad", fill="Gender"))
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to give another name to the ticks for example (A, B, C), and to add a sort of text part below the graph with A = Ministerio XXXX, or any other solution.

**UPDATE**

Problem solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the dimensions of the saved plot using `ggsave()`, e.g.

```
ministerios_genders <- ggplot(dfm_m,aes(x = nombre_entidad,y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", values = c("HOMBRE" = "blue",
                                         "MUJER" = "orange")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                   size=5, angle=75),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                   size=8, angle=90)) +
  ggtitle("Gender visitors gap for \nthe most important entities") +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title() +
  labs(y = "Proportions", x = "Year", fill="Gender")

ggsave(ministerios_genders, filename = "example.png", dpi = 300, height = 60, width = 30, units = "cm")
```

If the plot is larger you don't need to rename your variables; does that solve your problem?